# NHibernate ignoring GeneratedBy.Identity()

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to use NHibernate to serialize a moderately complex object graph*

Actual mapping was done via FNH, but I've dumped the HBM files and confirmed that the generated XML conforms to NHibernate conventions.

Here's a snippet of the HBM, just for grins:

```
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="obsv" optimistic-lock="version" name="Spc.Ofp.Tubs.DAL.Entities.PurseSeineActivity, TubsDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="s_daylog">
<id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <column name="s_daylog_id" not-null="true" />
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

This mapping results in the following SQL (via SQL debug, snipped for readability):

```
INSERT INTO obsv.s_daylog (/* columns 0 thru 20 snipped */s_daylog_id /* <-- PK from mapping! */) 
VALUES (/* parameters snipped */@p21); 
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p21 = NULL [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

I *believe* that the presence of the "select SCOPE_IDENTITY();" text confirms that
NHibernate partially understands what should happen.  I just don't understand why it's writing the PK column into the insert query.

I've been using the mappings for reading the graph just fine, so I'm fairly certain this isn't a basic mapping issue.

FWIW, Cascade is set to None (for other reasons, I need to work with these entities without
ramifications up and down the object graph).

*By moderately complex, I mean I have a object which has between 6 and 10 properties which are lists of child entities.  A good number of those child entities also have child entities.  In the most complex case, there are 5 generations of entities under the root entity.

Comment: As a quick follow up, I can hack this into working by explicitly setting a sql-insert statement that doesn't include the PK column.

Comment: Second follow up:  Now NHibernate is trying to update the identity column on update.  FML!

Comment: It looks to me like NHibernate knows it's a key, with an identity generator as you say. Your SQL does, however, show that it is trying to insert `NULL` as the Id.

Let's see the schema for this table, (for the appropriate cols) and the mapped class.

Comment: Do you also have a property defined in your mapping for `s_daylog_id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your mapping seems incorrect.

According to [the NHibernate Reference](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-id), the id tag has a "column" attribute to set the column name, not a child element.

Comment: Yep.  I have some crow to eat.  This entity had a child entity and I was mapping it using FNH's "References" method instead of "HasOne".

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dynamic-insert="true"`:

```
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" dynamic-insert="true" schema="obsv" optimistic-lock="version" name="Spc.Ofp.Tubs.DAL.Entities.PurseSeineActivity, TubsDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="s_daylog">
```